# Simple mechanics question - trapeze

Tags: classical-mechanics

> A woman of mass 50kg swings on a light trapeze, i.e. a light seat
>   suspended from a fixed point by a light rope.
>
> Her centre of mass, G, moves on the arc of a circle of radius 9m and
>   centre O. Initially the woman is at the point A, where OA is at 45
>   degrees to the vertical.

The first two parts of this question ask to calculate the gravitational potential energy lost as her centre of mass moves from A to B ( vertically below O), then assuming that there is no resistance to motion calculate her speed at B.

I approached part i using basic trigonometry and found that the loss in g.p.e. was approximately 1290J. For part ii, since $ 1/2 mv^2 = mgh$, i.e. $v^2=2gh$, it is simple to calculate that $ v = 7.19m/s $.

However I was unsure how to approach the second part:

> A more refined model takes account of resistance by assuming that there is a force of constant magnitude 20N acting in the direction opposing motion. It is also assumed that the woman "pushes off" from A with a speed of 1m/s. Show that her speed B is approximately 6.86m/s.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: As the force is assumed constant you can determine the energy lost to resistance as force x distance (=arc length), subtract this from the potential energy change, add her initial kinetic enrgy, and then detrmine her speed at B accordingly.

Comment: Ah I see now, thanks for the help

Comment: Remember, fundemental principle is conservation of energy in a closed system. Energy at start and end is the same, so initial potential + kinetic energy = final kinetic + potential + "dissapated" energy. The dissapated energy is in the form of heat, noise, air currents as a result of the work done against resistance.